# CSS - Is there a way to get rid of the selection rectangle after clicking a link?

Tags: css, hyperlink

Is there a way to get rid of the selection rectangle when clicking a link which does not refresh the current page entirely?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Do you mean the dotted outline of a target?

Try:

```
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

This would remove all focus outlines. IT's essentially the same as onclick in JavaScript terms. You might prefer to apply this to `a:focus`.

Comment: As pointed out in the answer to the question linked to below: "the outline is essential for keyboard-navigators as it designates where your selection is and, so, gives a hint to where your next 'tab' might go. Thus, it's inadvisable to remove this dotted-line selection."

Comment: I agree, I often add my own focus effects. An opacity decrease for images and a background/color change for navigation items for example.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding this:

```
onclick="this.blur()"
```

Discussed here as well

[(CSS?) Eliminating browser's 'selected' lines around a hyperlinked image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176695/css-eliminating-browsers-selected-lines-around-a-hyperlinked-image)

Comment: It's easier to use the CSS focus attribute, but this will work in older browsers.