# Seeing a rectangular box when clicking on img and anchor tags in IE

Tags: html, browser, anchor

If i click on anchor tag or img element in aspx page,that element will enclosed by dotted rectangular box. I am facing this problem in all anchor tags in IE browser and some times firefox and chorme also showing this problem.

How can i solve this problem? Is this browser side issue or our side issue?

Regards,
Karthik

Comment: Check  your css files. and create a new pure aspx page (NO master pages) in your application and create just one anchor tag and try that page. whether the problem still exists. And continue from there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179510/css-is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-the-selection-rectangle-after-clicking-a-link

Comment: this is a browser thing ( i wont say issue ) better ignore it. that's the browser outlining the clicked element for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179510/css-is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-the-selection-rectangle-after-clicking-a-link  - this link gives a perfect solution. thank u guy.

Answer (score 7):

[This tutorial](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/06/10/sharpen-your-site-by-removing-unwanted-link-border-outlines/) should help you remove focus borders, but there are usability issues to consider when doing this

Comment: what you mean about usability issues?

Comment: The focus border is there to show which element currently has focus. This is essential for keyboard users, as without something showing which element is focused, they will find it hard to tab through elements

Answer (score 1):

For me this rectangular box encloses only anchors, not img (unless they are also anchors). Try setting outline of this elements to 0.

Comment: You are correct (though you don't need img in that rule at all), but an kitten dies every time someone does this.

Comment: Right, I didn't think anyone would actually use it literally on his website... Better delete the example from this answer. :)

Comment: Heh, well, let's just say there are a lot of dead kittens out there. Someone I know actually created a web page  called http://outlinenone.com/ tho :)