# Navicon Transformicons blue border

Tags: jquery, html, css, icons, transform

I was playing with [sara soueidan](http://sarasoueidan.com/demos/navicon-transformicons/) navicon and after analysing it there's still something I quite dont understand.

There's a blue selector arround those icons that I can't seem to remove, is it specific to his method or simple misunderstanding of the jquery ?

here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/Ah6XA/

```
    <button type="button" role="button" aria-label="Toggle Navigation" id="mbtn" class="lines-button x">
      <span class="lines"></span>
    </button>
#mbtn {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 1em;
      border: none;
      background: none;
    }
    #mbtn span {
      display: block;
    }

    .lines-button {
      padding: 2rem 1rem;
      transition: .3s;
      cursor: pointer;
      /* */
    }

    .lines {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 4rem;
      height: 0.57143rem;
      background: #211f20;
      border-radius: 0.28571rem;
      transition: 0.3s;
      position: relative;
    }
    .lines:before, .lines:after {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 4rem;
      height: 0.57143rem;
      background: #211f20;
      border-radius: 0.28571rem;
      transition: 0.3s;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      content: '';
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0.28571rem center;
      transform-origin: 0.28571rem center;
    }
    .lines:before {
      top: 1rem;
    }
    .lines:after {
      top: -1rem;
    }

    .lines-button:hover .lines:before {
      top: 1.14286rem;
    }
    .lines-button:hover .lines:after {
      top: -1.14286rem;
    }

    .lines-button.close {
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
      transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
    }

    .lines-button.x.close .lines {
      background: transparent;
    }
    .lines-button.x.close .lines:before, .lines-button.x.close .lines:after {
      -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      top: 0;
      width: 4rem;
    }
    .lines-button.x.close .lines:before {
      -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
      transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
    }
    .lines-button.x.close .lines:after {
      -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
      transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
    }



var anchor = document.querySelectorAll('button');

[].forEach.call(anchor, function(anchor){
  var open = false;
  anchor.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(!open){
      this.classList.add('close');
      open = true;
    }
    else{
      this.classList.remove('close');
      open = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is just the selection/focus rectangle that the web browser is adding, like it does when you click on regular links or focus a form field. It's easy to get rid of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179510/css-is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-the-selection-rectangle-after-clicking-a-link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the border on mobile, you have to add this:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```